# Undefined variable in Octave

Tags: octave

I wrote this function for the differential equation:

```
#odefun.m
function [dy] = odefun (t, y)

m = 10;
k = 100;
c = 20;

dy = zeros(2, 1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = (-c*y(2) - k*y(1) + F(t))/m;

endfunction

function [Fvalue] = F(t);
  
F0 = 1;
omega = 2;

Fvalue = F0*cos(omega*t);

endfunction
```

And then in a separate file I try to plot:

```
tspan = 0:0.01:10;

y0 = [0 0];

[T Y] = ode45(@odefun, tspan, y0);

figure;
plot(T, Y);
legend('y..1', 'y..2');
xlabel(' time [s]');
```

When I run the program, I get an error:

> error: 'y' undefined near line 8 column 9
> error: called from
> odefun at line 8 column 7

I took a sample code from the tutorial, everything works there, but but it doesn’t work for me. However, when I put everything into the same file, it does work. How can I make it work when using different files?

Comment: Please don't tag spam. As the tag descriptions of [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave] clearly mention: only use both tags when asking about the differences/similarities between the two languages. They are not the same, and code that works in one doesn't necessarily work in the other (especially given the function-specific `end` in Octave).

Comment: Now I tried to write the same code in one file and run it. Everything worked, and the charts were built. Can you tell me why this happens?